# Setting up a SharePoint 2013 development environment

Tags: development-enviroment

After factoring in licensing and all that what is the **most cost effective** way of setting up a SharePoint 2013 dev environment for 4-7 developers. We are considering buying desktops and putting a vm on each on with the dev environment set up on there or potentially upgrading a VM server to accomodate all the extra ram needed. Licensing seems expensive. Is getting the Ultimate MSDN the best option there? What about Office 365 or azure, will these suit our needs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MSDN is the most cost effective way to get all you need to SharePoint 2013 development. You do not need Ultimate, as [Premium subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx) will do.

Couple of notes:

- Azure can be used instead of having local Virtual Machines, but it does not provide you with licenses for SharePoint and Visual Studio
- Office 365 can be used if you will be developing only SharePoint 2013 Apps and not SharePoint 2013 Farm solutions. You still need to license Visual Studio 2012 on your PCs
- A number of MSDN Subscriptions is available as part of [Microsoft Partner Program benefits](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/Pages/Membership/core-benefits.aspx). If your company is a partner, or can become one, this can also help you optimize your costs. (Please check terms and talk to your Microsoft Partner manager as these might not cover your needs).

Comment: Does every developer need premium or can one dev build the dev environments and all the other devs use a pro license?

Comment: Yes, every developer needs MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate becoming a [Microsoft (development) partner](http://partner.microsoft.com). A lot of the software you require will then be included for an annual fee.

This will also put you on Microsoft's radar for possible marketing and other such support from your local Microsoft office if you intend to create software to on-sell to new or existing Microsoft customers - especially if that software sale will help them sell their licenses.

Also included (depending on level of subscription or competencies obtained):

- Support tickets for break-fix (4 hr response) and other issues
- Advisory hours: I have x customer problem, which Microsoft software should I use? (and other such advice-like questions)

Comment: Could you site a reference for this? I didn't know that the free tier of the partner network actually provided you with anything that related directly to SharePoint.

Comment: https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/Pages/Membership/core-benefits.aspx

Comment: Strange, I posted a link but it seems to have disappeared from the post...thanks @toni

Comment: But if you look at the foot note for the first item it says `Microsoft Action Pack Solution Provider subscribers only.` Action Pack is not free.

Comment: I m just pushing the issue because when I worked for an MS Partner we paid for the software in the Action Pack. We did not get any of it free.

Comment: Yes, you need to pay to be a partner (the price depends on the partner level and region) but you will get a number of MSDN subscriptions as part of partner benefits and this is usually cheaper than buying these separately. However this might or might not be the best way for the OP.

Comment: I've now added more detail to my question and removed the misleading "free" keyword. I wrote "free" because I consider the annual subscription a drop-in-the-bucket in savings for software that will help you run your business AND the software that you'll use to make money.